# Updating single value in a deep nested map

Tags: elixir

I have this map:

```
%{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "questions">,
  __struct__: MyApp.Question,
  active: true,
  description: "player points",
  id: 118,
  inserted_at: ~N[2018-08-26 19:48:22.501445],
  reserved: %Statcasters.Questions.Reserved{
    information: %{
      game_id: "b796cbe9-0bb6-4aaf-98b0-5da81c337208",
      player_id: "8ffb69ce-9a6b-44a6-8e8f-c069235d2d31",
      player_name: "Lebron James"
    },
    inputs: [%{label: "Player Points", type: "text"}]
  },
  type: "NBA",
  updated_at: ~N[2018-08-26 19:48:22.504193]
}
```

How can I update `reserved.information.player_id` from `8ffb69ce-9a6b-44a6-8e8f-c069235d2d31` to `12345`?

In Ruby this is a trivial change because of mutability but I'm having trouble finding the best way to update it in Elixir.

#### Current attempt (not working)

```
Map.put(map, :player_id, "053600fb-3aae-422f-a9cb-9d102cca301f")
```

This doesn't work because it just adds the player_id to first level of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#put_in/3):

```rb
input = %{
  reserved: %{
    information: %{player_id: 42}
  }
}

put_in(input, ~w|reserved information player_id|a, -1)
#⇒ %{reserved: %{information: %{player_id: -1}}}
```

Whether you want to change/adjust the value instead of simply putting the new one, use [`Kernel.get_and_update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#get_and_update_in/3). For the latter to work with *structs*, this struct should implement [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html) behaviour.

Comment: When I try that, I get:  `(UndefinedFunctionError) function Statcasters.Questions.Reserved.get_and_update/3 is undefined `  Of course, I defined my own Statcasters.Questions.Reserved struct for my example, so maybe that's why.

Comment: @7stud _That_ works perfectly. “Use `Kernel.get_and_update_in/3`” does not mean it will work out of the box, one should implement `Access` behaviour for `Statcasters.Questions.Reserved` upfront.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I update reserved.information.player_id from
>   8ffb69ce-9a6b-44a6-8e8f-c069235d2d31 to 12345?

```rb
defmodule Statcasters.Questions.Reserved do
  defstruct information: %{}, inputs: []
end

defmodule My do

  def go do
    map = %{
      __meta__: "hello world",
      __struct__: "boo hoo",
      active: true,
      description: "player points",
      id: 118,
      inserted_at: ~N[2018-08-26 19:48:22.501445],
      reserved: %Statcasters.Questions.Reserved{
        information: %{
          game_id: "b796cbe9-0bb6-4aaf-98b0-5da81c337208",
          player_id: "8ffb69ce-9a6b-44a6-8e8f-c069235d2d31",
          player_name: "Lebron James"
        },
        inputs: [%{label: "Player Points", type: "text"}]
      },
      type: "NBA",
      updated_at: ~N[2018-08-26 19:48:22.504193]
    }

    put_in(map.reserved.information.player_id, 12345)
  end


end
```

In iex:

```rb
~/elixir_programs$ iex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> c "my.exs"
[My, Statcasters.Questions.Reserved]

iex(2)> My.go     
%{
  __meta__: "hello world",
  __struct__: "boo hoo",
  active: true,
  description: "player points",
  id: 118,
  inserted_at: ~N[2018-08-26 19:48:22.501445],
  reserved: %Statcasters.Questions.Reserved{
    information: %{
      game_id: "b796cbe9-0bb6-4aaf-98b0-5da81c337208",
      player_id: 12345,
      player_name: "Lebron James"
    },
    inputs: [%{label: "Player Points", type: "text"}]
  },
  type: "NBA",
  updated_at: ~N[2018-08-26 19:48:22.504193]
} 

iex(3)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your struct is stored in a variable called `struct`:

```elixir
put_in(struct.reserved.information.player_id, "12345")
```